# I can't get go_session_id

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, python-requests, httprequest

I can't figure out how to get cookies with the go_session_id parameter, it turns out with other parameters. I attach the program code:

```
import requests, fake_useragent
user = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random
headers = {'user-agent': user}
number = '+79614722233'
sess = requests.Session()
r = sess.get('https://payment.mts.ru/', headers=headers)
print(r)
print(sess.cookies.get_dict())
r = sess.post('https://sso.mtsbank.ru/api/v2/login', headers=headers, json={'login': number[1:]})
print(r)
print(r.text)
```

And I will also write the text of the post request that I should send through the program:

```
General:
Request URL: https://sso.mtsbank.ru/api/v2/login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 82.202.190.35:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Response Headers:
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: https://sso.mtsbank.ru
access-control-expose-headers: token
cache-control: no-store
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 85
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 02 Mar 2023 15:18:09 GMT
pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx
server-timing: intid;desc=442001b93309c9d4
strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000
traceparent: 00-0000000000000000442001b93309c9d4-442001b93309c9d4-01
tracestate: in=442001b93309c9d4;442001b93309c9d4
vary: Origin
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: DENY
x-instana-l: 1
x-instana-s: 442001b93309c9d4
x-instana-t: 442001b93309c9d4
x-request-id: 63db13dd32b335f42d03abc81e912070
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
Request Headers:
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 23
Content-Type: application/json
Cookie: go_session_id=NDRmMDJlOTctMWQwZi00NWNmLTg1NDQtYTIwMzUwNjM5Mjgz.69231fdcd5289f41a9ab883da8f6849432860b2f
Host: sso.mtsbank.ru
Origin: https://sso.mtsbank.ru
Referer: https://sso.mtsbank.ru/login/mtsmoney/auth/
sec-ch-ua: "Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Yandex";v="23"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 YaBrowser/23.1.4.778 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36
Request Payload:
{login: "79611234567"}
```

I tried to get cookies and thought my parameter would be there, but it wasn't there:

```
<Response [200]>
{'TS016bb39a': '012019f3d42797fbeffa4e2cbd9f9d87c1ca95471b9a4cee3cb32c4aabb7088b2e61e457ecdf4a6a42515b7871d4904eaef2d8c76eaa224fe90825b8edfd74caa67da8e490edf6ae95b4ef18e2db2ff4eb902a57d53af4a72c2631f9d94785f0112f9d586f382052eefbf098a255f1a98151c8bda0', '.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.q1sNu47QVQs': 'CfDJ8NxAinrLot9AhyO3UZA71zHHTSizyDYnxj0ckopYqbIjHextEQGQfbOf4lgrDa4z2u4S65qZF5yAkFtp0Woz3RN6UY-zNUYfdP1gEgPBHSlui7NU95w0Zd_PGxHZ6ENdtvB9Niuk8XUVwYL_w4EgH9w', '.AspNetCore.RegionId': 'MOW', 'StickyID': '!f3egRLHvs4AE7gopFL1Kx71Z9S8d2pjo/pE18UVcgfWfT96HpuNFY8A6uJsr1bkvJIBEMJ0Bh4fwow=='}
<Response [400]>
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed","error_id":"fc6ce41836f1b2296ce26f83f4bdee7a"}
```

The site complains about the missing parameter, that is, the go_session_id.
I know that I need to add the go_session_id parameter to the post request parameters in my application code, but I want to GET this parameter, because most likely such a parameter is unstable.
Answer me with a code in which this parameter can be obtained. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

on this site, the go_session_id cookie is obtained by requesting a request to "https://ssoauth.mtsbank.ru/authorize?client_id=mts-money-web-mtsid"

[see this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piB7h.png)

Comment: How did you find this link?

Comment: @VasCer03 i traffic capture with Fiddler